# Static method to assign non static variable

Tags: java, variables, methods, static

I have two clases GUI ( That renderes my main JFrame ) and Print class ( That is invoked by JButton on GUI class ). Now on my GUI Class i have JTextArea and a method:

```
void setOutput(String data)
{
   // output is JTextArea
   output.setText(data);
}
```

However the data is provided the the Print JFrame where i have a JButton with action listener:

```
sizOpt.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{       
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
       // textfield is a JTextField component
       String data = textfield.getText();   


       // My problem is here i need to invoke the setOutput
       // method in GUI to output the string however i cant call that method in
       // any way but making it static or calling new GUI which will create a new
       // Instance of GUI class
       GUI.setOutput(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: So... what´s the question? Ah OK sorry seen it, but really you shouldn't put your actual question inside a comment in the code sample.

Comment: Sorry for that is 5AM and my eye's are bledding and my mind is nearing breaking point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer: don't use static anything here at all.

The only thing that should be static is your main method, and that's probably it. If you need to call a method on the GUI, then call it on an ***instance*** of the visualized GUI, not as a static method. Often the tricky part is getting that valid reference, and you are correct that you shouldn't create a new GUI object, but again don't try to do a non-working static solution. Some ways to get the valid reference are via a constructor parameter or a setter method.

i.e.,

```
public class PrintJFrame extends JFrame {
  private GUI gui;

  public PrintJFrame(GUI gui) {
    this.gui = gui;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Now in your ActionListener you can call a method on the correct GUI reference held by the gui variable. Next we'll talk about why you should avoid having classes extend JFrames and similar GUI components.
Next we'

Comment: What i had was in my main method which was in a seperate class i called a class atribute GUI g; and in main i had g = new GUI(); then i had a static method reference(String data) that called g.setOutput(data); and i called main class.reference in my print class. However i like your approach much more so im will rewrite as its not much work and will end up working better.

Answer (score 1):

Make a static reference to the instance of your JFrame subclass, with an appropriate instance method on the JFrame to retrieve the text.

Comment: Wouldn't he be better off simply calling appropriate methods on non-static instances of the other class?

Comment: I was trying to suggest minimal changes to the code, but re-thinking it wouldn't be that much effort to just make a static reference to the JFrame. Have amended by answer.